# Displaying all of the array past certain amount

Tags: c#, arrays, split

```
    Text = textBox.Text;

    if (Text.StartsWith("!say"))
    {
        string[] CurrentText = Text.Trim().Split(' ');
        label1.Text = CurrentText[1];
        label2.Text = CurrentText[2] += CurrentText[3];
    }
```

I've done a lot of searching and it's probably easy, but I couldn't find anything, but I want anything past CurrentText[2] to be put onto `label2.Text`, not just the 2nd and 3rd, is there anyway to do this? Also, how can I keep the spaces in between(such as if I put `"!say Hello Hello World!"` would come out as

```
  label1 = Hello
```

and

```
  label2 = Hello World!
```

with the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
label2.Text = String.Join(" ", CurrentText.Skip(2).ToArray());
```

Since the array indexes are zero based `CurrentText[0]` and `CurrentText[1]` have to be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to take care about the first " ", why not use this:

```
int index = Text.IndexOf(" ");

label1.Text = text.Substring(0, index);
label2.Text = text.Substring(index + 1);
```

Comment: Your first substring should use `index-1`, no?

Comment: @DStanley: Neither -1 nor +1, nothing is the correct answer :-). Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Close, however it has to be random on what the user can input. for instance !say helloworld would put helloworld as label1, while hello puts hello as label1. Yours puts !say and if you change it to say 5, it will put Hello into the box but nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Text = textBox.Text;

```
if (Text.StartsWith("!say"))
{
    string[] CurrentText = Text.Trim().Split(' ');
    label1.Text = CurrentText[1];
    label2.Text = string.Join(", ", CurrentText.Skip(2).ToArray());
}
```

This will help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
label2.Text += string.Join(" ", CurrentText, 1, CurrentText.Length-1);
```

To me, Linq seems like overkill in this situation.